# Combining different Columns from different tables into distinct table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I need to combine 3 different columns from 3 tables and result set should be a distinct table.

Attached to the blue table is my question and the yellow table is my expected answer. How Can I Get the expected table?

I don't want duplicates in the name which is column 1.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: which sql version and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Is that the 3 tables with data? Show us the expected result as well!

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I have SQ: Server 2012 and I tried Union and  Full Outer joins

Comment: @jarlh I posted a picture of Expected Result but I don't even see the picture Myself. I need to learn on how to use this properly. Please let me know if you see the picture of my expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Full Outer Joins

The question doesn't give us much to go on so I am making almost no assumptions about the data.  There doesn't seem to be a 'Name' table and none of the 3 tables appears to represent a complete list of names.  So, I'm going to close my eyes and type out a couple of full outer joins:

```
Select t1.name, t1.country, t2.food, t3.movie 
    from table1 t1
    full outer join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
    full outer join table3 t3 on t3.name = t1.name
```

This will give you **all of the names** (with no assumptions that any one table would need to contain a complete list), each one listed just once (provided they don't already appear multiple times in any one table) along with any data associated with that name from any of the three tables.

**Update**
So here is an update (see comment below) that replaces the names of the countries, foods, and movies with just 'yes' or 'no'.

```
Select 
        t1.name, 
        case when t1.country is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as country,
        case when t2.food is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as food,
        case when t3.movie is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as movie
    from table1 t1
    full outer join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
    full outer join table3 t3 on t3.name = t1.name
```

...and rewritten with generic Column1, Column2 in case that's the issue:

```
Select 
        t1.Column1 as name, 
        case when t1.Column2 is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as country,
        case when t2.Column2 is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as food,
        case when t3.Column2 is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as movie
    from table1 t1
    full outer join table2 t2 on t1.Column1 = t2.Column1
    full outer join table3 t3 on t3.Column1 = t1.Column1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think my question was not clear. All the 3 tables will have 1 column 'Name' which could have same values or different. Like CAry could be in all 3 tables but Liz could be in only 1.
The Result I want is 1st column to have distinct list of names and another column to say yes/No. if Cary has been to country than yes if not no. 
When I did full outer join all the columns gave me names. I want Name in 1 column and yes or no in other columns

Comment: @Lina - I have an updated solution here for you.  If it helps you, don't forget to 'Accept' it as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lina - Have you seen these since I posted those updates?

Comment: I didn't see it. I will give this a Try and let you know. thank you so much for taking time to help me. If the solution you gave works than how do I accept it as a answer? I am a new user here

Comment: I see how to accept it now. let me try and work on the solutions

Comment: I couldn't get an expected answer using full outer join.



select Number, SUM(I) as Country, SUM(D) as Place, SUM(A) as City from 
(
SELECT distinct(number), CASE WHEN m.number IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS I,0 AS D, 0 AS A
FROM dbo.country M(NOLOCK) 
Union
SELECT distinct(number),0 as I,CASE WHEN D IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS D, 0 AS A
FROM dbo.Food F(NOLOCK)

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with an answer to my question.

I used union function to get expected result.

Basically I had 3 tables with one same column name (number). 
for instance 700 could be in table 1 and 3 but not in 2 and 701 could be only in table 1.

I used this query:

```
select Number, SUM(I) as Country, SUM(D) as Place, SUM(A) as City from 
(
SELECT distinct(number), CASE WHEN m.number IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS I,0 AS D, 0 AS A
FROM dbo.country M(NOLOCK) 
Union
SELECT distinct(number),0 as I,CASE WHEN D IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS D, 0 AS A
FROM dbo.Food F(NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Distinct is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected row. Skip those redundant parentheses and do `SELECT DISTINCT number, CASE WHEN ...` instead. Anyhow, `UNION` removes all duplicates here, so you can skip the DISTINCT and simply do just SELECT.